# Combine/Join lines in Notepad++ based on separator

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text log file in the following format.

```
****************************************************************************************
line1
line2
line3
****************************************************************************************
line4
line5
line6
****************************************************************************************
```

Is there a way in Notepad++ to combine lines between the "*" separators so the data looks like below

```
****************************************************************************************
line1 line2 line3
****************************************************************************************
line4 line5 line6
****************************************************************************************
```

Thanks!

Comment: Somehow I doubt it qualifies as programming question... But you definitely can as k how to write a program to do that using some programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!\*)\R(?!\*)`
- Replace with:     # a space
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\*)         # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't a * before
\R              # any kind of linebreak
(?!\*)          # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't * after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]